# User variable from include-file in function

Tags: php, variables, include

I am trying to accomplish the following:
I have a file `conn.inc.php` containing the class called `DatabaseConnection`:

[pastebin](http://pastebin.com/9MdNXjgw) (since it's a bit lengthy)
Then I have a second include called `bootstrap.inc.php`:

```
<?php
    global $dbcon;
    $dbcon = new DatabaseConnection();
    $dbcon->setHostname("localhost");
    $dbcon->setUsername("root");
    $dbcon->setPassword("password");
    $dbcon->setDatabase("database");
?>
```

And I have a third overall `functions.inc.php`, which is designed to be included if neccessary:

```
<?php include 'conn.inc.php'; ?>
<?php include 'bootstrap.inc.php'; ?>
<?php 

function myFunction()
{
    $db = $dbcon->getConnection();
    $sql = "CALL ssp_MySP()";
    $result = $db->query($sql) or trigger_error($db->error."[$sql]");

    ....
}
?>
```

Now every time I call myFunction I get an error when I am opening the connection -> `$db = $dbcon->getConnection();` saying that the varibale `$dbcon` is undefined.

How can I use `$dbcon` inside my functions located in `functions.inc.php`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$db` variable inside your function is a local variable (of that function). If you want to access the variable(s) outside the function, use the [`global`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.global) keyword. This has to do with the [variable scope](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

```
<?php include 'conn.inc.php'; ?>
<?php include 'bootstrap.inc.php'; ?>
<?php 

function myFunction()
{
    global $dbcon;
    $db = $dbcon->getConnection();
    $sql = "CALL ssp_MySP()";
    $result = $db->query($sql) or trigger_error($db->error."[$sql]");

    ....
}
?>
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood something here. I want to use `$dbcon` inside my function(s), which don't seem to work (despite making `$dbcon global` in `bootstrapper.inc.php`)

Comment: @seph Sorry, you need to make the `$dbcon` global in the function.

Comment: Wouldn't I overwrite the `$dbcon`-var coming from `bootstrap.inc.php` by doing so?

Comment: No you wouldn't. That's how you do it. (Also read about it in the [php documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.global).)

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm newish to PHP, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `global $dbcon;` at the beginning of each of the files.

Comment: I tried adding it to my `bootsrap.inc.php`, but no success. What do you mean with "each of the files? Since I always include the `functions.inc.php` I thought that adding that to my `bootstrapper.inc.php` would be sufficient.

Comment: You need it once in the `bootstrap.inc.php` to specify that the variable is available globally, and again in every file you intend to use it in to bring the variable into that file.

Comment: I'm a bit confused now. My intention is to only include the `functions.inc.php`-file on the other files. And I thought since `bootstrap.inc.php` is included in my `functions.inc.php` specifying `$dbcon`globally inside `bootstrap.inc.php` would be enough (see edit in opening post)?

Comment: You need to add `global $dbcon;` in `functions.inc.php`.

Comment: Think of the global variables as in a main pool. Each time you call `global $somevariable;` it says that `$somevariable` in that file should refer to the global copy. That goes for reads, writes, method calls, anything. You need to call `global` in any file you want to use `$somevariable` in.

Comment: thanks for simplyfing this to me. It was a hard decision whom to give those additional internet-points :).